# check for bool(glutGetWindow) before calling

Tags: python, opengl, glut, pyopengl

I'm new to Linux Mint and medium new to Python. I'm trying to run a program that uses OpenGL. The installation of OpenGL seemed to have worked fine, but when i run my program i get the following error:

```
File "/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.0a3-py2.7.egg/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 385, in __call__
    self.__name__, self.__name__,
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutGetWindow, check for bool(glutGetWindow) before calling
```

Comment: have you installed glut/ freeglut?

Comment: Ok, i actually see how easy it was to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to install glut so you can't call those functions.